# Unable to re-install whatsapp on Asus mobile

Tags: installation, asus-zenfone-2

While installing WhatsApp from Play Store, error message is displayed with error code 26.

Comment: This question is for a different phone, but the suggestions might help you too: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/152144/cant-install-app-error-code-26

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to try:

**1.Restart your phone**

**2.Clear play store data:**

Go to *settings -> apps -> Google play store -> storage -> clear data.*

3.If that doesn't help, then **remove your Google account and then add it back again**

Go to settings -> accounts -> Google -> example@Gmail.com -> menu -> remove account.

Then, add it back, and try installing the app. If you cannot remove the account, just add a new one instead